# Writing data to data lake gen2 for power bi consumption

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-lake

If we have some data coming in from a marketing platform on an hourly rate with behavior data (see this as events or rows in a CSV file).

I want to put that in a data lake gen 2 with the purpose of allowing power bi devs to easily consume the data and use it.

As a dev, what can I do to make this data more optimized for the power bi users? Should I put stuff in time portions? Should I just drop raw CSV files and hope its not a performance issue for powerbi?

I ask because I saw the files that power platform data flows are generating, and wonder if i should do similar? maybe there is toolking/sdk for c# to do this already. What should I consider in this task before implementing something?

Answer (score 0):

I must say that the question is very generic and its tough to provide guidance without viewing the data . Since you are talking about the marketing data I am assuming that its huge , I must say that PBI does handle huge data pretty good . Anyways the question is regarding how do we keep the data in ADLA gen 2 . I suggest that you can go with

Container\year\month\day\hr
eg
****2020\07\12\23****

if possible I could go for

Container\year\month\day\hr\mm
eg
**2020\07\12\23\59**

This approach will make the csv file smaller , which I think is always better .

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, and problems are likely dealt with but anyway in case anyone else comes looking...
You asked "What should I consider in this task before implementing something?"

If you are not going to provide a curated layer with data bricks or synapse, then the main question I would ask is if the data will be imported or if direct query will be used.

Imported then CSV performs well, but you can optimize by removing any unwanted columns, etc. PowerBI does a pretty good job on compression and handling large data files. One area it is not so good at is importing large numbers of smaller csv files. It is better to merge these into single larger files.CSV performs better than Parquet when importing.

Direct Query then I would look into converting the CSV to Parquet which performs better than CSV for querying (honestly not even sure direct query is available on csv??) But if looking for direct query I would strongly consider a curation layer with Data Bricks or Synapse to handle joins and aggregates and denormalisation. Fabric now has a new direct query available which performs much better in certain situations, bring best of both import and direct query but the current restrictions means it is not always applicable.